# tuples to arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, type-conversion

When I do this:

```
print(type(params2))
y = np.asarray(params2)
```

I get the following error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

My params2 looks like this:

```
>>>type(params2)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> params2
(array([  2.16003254,  35.41060695]), array([[  3.56496896e-02,  -5.90834196e+00],
   [ -5.90834196e+00,   1.03644107e+03]]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
y = np.vstack(params2)
```

then `y =`:

```
array([[  2.16003254e+00,   3.54106070e+01],
   [  3.56496896e-02,  -5.90834196e+00],
   [ -5.90834196e+00,   1.03644107e+03]])
```

If this isn't the result you want, please write out what you'd like to have.

Answer (score 0):

The tuple passed into the array is not generalized. Input to asarray can only be among lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples of lists and ndarrays.

For example, this works fine:

```
params2 = (np.array([  2.16003254,  35.41060695]), 
           np.array([  3.56496896e-02, 5.90834196e+00]),
           np.array([ -5.90834196e+00,   1.03644107e+03]))

np.asarray(params2)
```

but your tuple was not homogeneous.